# bookmark home page embedded with an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, bookmarks

The content of the iframe is actually perl-generated html loaded when the links on sidebar of the home page is clicked. But even if it was just plain html. Is there a way to bookmark the home page along with a specified iframe content?

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a query string or hash tag to the URL.  Then have your iframe load the HTML based on the query/hash input (after sanitized, of course).  That way, when a user bookmarks the page, the appropriate content will populate the iframe.